# Chrome Extension: Injecting Scripts Into Newly Created Windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm currently trying to build a chrome extension, of which part of it creates a new "popup" window using:

```
chrome.windows.create({
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL("myHTML.html"),
            type: "popup"
        }, function (window) {
            // Trace tab id which is created with this query 
            myTabID = window.tabs[0].id;
            });
```

Which loads up a new window from my html file and stores the tab ID of the created window.

But what I want to do is to inject Jquery and "myScript.js" into "myHTML.html" once it is created by doing:

```
//Listen for vocab list window creation
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Inject script into chosen tab after it is loaded completely
    if (tabId == myTabID && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        // Inject jQuery in current tab
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            "file": "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        }, function () {
            console.log("Injected jquery into page");
        });
        // Inject script in current tab
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            "file": "myScript.js"
        }, function () {
            console.log("Injected myScript into page");
        });
    }
});
```

But when I try this, it gives me an error stating:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript:
Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://<my extension id>
/myHTML.html". Extension manifest must request permission
to access this host.
```

My current manifest.json permssions are as follows:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
```

I've tried looking for the answer but I can't seem to find any that really address my issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: executeScript won't inject content scripts into your own extension page because it's not a web page. All you need is to specify the scripts in your HTML file using `script` tag just like on any other page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I realized that when I had tried what you were saying previously, I was getting the same error because I had a bit of inline js but the rest of the script ran fine as a file. Thanks again!